# Can SSH(SFTP) server have multiple fingerprints?

Tags: ssh, sftp, fingerprint

I am creating automated SFTP-client with Java and I need of course to save the server SSH fingerprint for each server but is it possible that the server has two or more unique fingerprints?

Is it possible that there are loadbalanced SFTP-service that has multiple SSH-servers behind the loadbalancer and they each have unique fingerprint? Or is it somehow forced that they are they all using the same fingerprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

It's possible for a single server to have multiple hostkeys for alternative algorithms (in fact *most* servers support e.g. RSA + EdDSA), but only a single hostkey is chosen for each connection, and for clients it should be enough to remember just one.

In case of load-balanced services, there is no magic mechanism that would *force* all nodes to share the same key. But in practice, it is very likely that the system administrator will just copy the same keypair across all nodes, to make it easier for users to connect.

---

In more detail:

- First of all, even a *single* server can always have multiple hostkeys with different algorithms – for example: one ssh-rsa key, one ssh-ed25519 key, and one ecdsa-nistp256 key.

  The handshake requires the client to choose one key, and it's usually just that one key's fingerprint which gets remembered. However, some clients – e.g. PuTTY – allow rekeying the connection with all available hostkeys, to support algorithm migration.

  For example, you connect using the server's ssh-rsa key but additionally remember its ssh-ed25519 fingerprint. Later, if the server disables ssh-rsa support, you can now use ssh-ed25519 without re-prompting the user.
- When connecting to load-balanced services, some clients will allow multiple known hostkeys *even of the same type* to be approved manually.

  For example, if the same hostname is shared by several nodes, the OpenSSH client lets you manually add all of their public keys to ~/.ssh/known_hosts and will accept any matching entry.

  However, OpenSSH will not do this *automatically* – once it knows the first key, it will treat any change as a fatal error. So in practice, I would assume that sysadmins actually try to avoid bad user experience and just clone the same hostkey to all load-balanced nodes.

Summary of existing clients:

- PuTTY can track multiple keys per server, but only one for each algorithm. In other words, it requires the [hostname, port, algorithm] combination to be unique.
- OpenSSH can track multiple keys per server, without any uniqueness requirements.
- *<Other clients?>*

Comment: Based on this great answer I think I will at least create the possibility to configure multiple fingerprints for single server though it might be that it is never needed.